# Young's double slit problems: What is the difference between first bright fringe vs first maximum vs first order maximum?

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment

Sometimes the question related to young double slit will trick me by asking you to find the width of first maximum or first order maximum or first bright fringe from the central maximum? What are their differences actually?